# PyTest Fixtures - SQAlchemy connections not closing when running in Docker

Tags: python, mysql, docker, sqlalchemy

I am using pytest to create tests for my FastAPI based app. It is using SQLAlchemy + pymysql to connect to a MySQL database using the following code:

```
def override_get_db():
    engine = create_engine(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL, poolclass=NullPool)
    SessionLocal = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=True, bind=engine)
    print("Session created")
    db = SessionLocal()
    try:
        yield db
    finally:
        print("Session closed")
        db.close()
    engine.dispose()
```

It is then injected as dependency in the FastAPI app definition. To get the versions out of the way (the same used on my local environment on macOS as well as in the Docker container):

- Python: 3.10.3
- SQLAlchemy: 1.4.41
- pymysql: 1.0.2
- outest: 7.1.3

Locally, pytest run through fine. All tests succeed and the final result is printed, before pytest exits. Within the Docker container though (both locally on Docker desktop as well as on the Gitlab runner with docker executor), the actual test run through fine, but then pytest doesn't exit and gets stuck forever.

After further investigation, I've identified the point where it gets stuck - there is a pytest fixture doing the very basic database operations:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def create_database():
    """
    Create the database using the root credentials towards the test database instance
    """

    # Connect to the database
    connection = pymysql.connect(
        host=settings.test_db_host,
        user="root",
        password=settings.test_db_root_password,
        port=settings.test_db_port,
        cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor,
        autocommit=True,
    )

    # Create the new database
    with closing(connection.cursor()) as cursor:
        sql = "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS %s;" % settings.test_db_database
        cursor.execute(sql)

    yield

    with closing(connection.cursor()) as cursor:
        # And drop it after the tests have finished
        sql = "DROP DATABASE %s;" % settings.test_db_database
        cursor.execute(sql)

    connection.close()
```

The app gets stuck when trying to drop the database. Further investigation on the database shows that not all connections have been closed and `DROP DATABASE` is waiting for lock releases (see line 3 and the open connections in the following lines):

```
mysql> SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
+------+-----------------+------------------+--------------+---------+-------+---------------------------------+----------------------------+
| Id   | User            | Host             | db           | Command | Time  | State                           | Info                       |
+------+-----------------+------------------+--------------+---------+-------+---------------------------------+----------------------------+
|    5 | event_scheduler | localhost        | NULL         | Daemon  | 91256 | Waiting on empty queue          | NULL                       |
| 2598 | root            | localhost        | NULL         | Query   |     0 | init                            | SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST      |
| 5874 | root            | 172.20.0.4:50410 | NULL         | Query   |     6 | Waiting for table metadata lock | DROP DATABASE backend_test |
| 5918 | root            | 172.20.0.4:50498 | backend_test | Sleep   |     8 |                                 | NULL                       |
| 5944 | root            | 172.20.0.4:50550 | backend_test | Sleep   |     7 |                                 | NULL                       |
| 5963 | root            | 172.20.0.4:50588 | backend_test | Sleep   |     7 |                                 | NULL                       |
| 5999 | root            | 172.20.0.4:50660 | backend_test | Sleep   |     7 |                                 | NULL                       |
| 6012 | root            | 172.20.0.4:50686 | backend_test | Sleep   |     7 |                                 | NULL                       |
+------+-----------------+------------------+--------------+---------+-------+---------------------------------+----------------------------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I added the `print()` statements in the database session code shown above and noticed the following behaviour:

- When running the code locally in my local environment, `Session created` and `Session closed` each get called exactly 93 times.
- When running in the Docker container, `Session created` is also called 93 times, but the code closing the connection is executed less. The exact number depends on the run, but typically its between 84 or 85 executes, which means connections are left open.

The mysql version is `8.0.28` and both the local and the Docker test use the exact same MySQL server instance.

Why is the ´finally` block not called when running the code in Docker compared to locally?

Edit: In case it matters, the Dockerfile used to build the app container:

```
FROM python:3.10.3-slim as python-base

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1 \
    PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1 \
    PIP_NO_CACHE_DIR=off \
    PIP_DISABLE_PIP_VERSION_CHECK=on \
    PIP_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT=100 \
    POETRY_VERSION=1.2.1 \
    POETRY_HOME="/opt/poetry" \
    POETRY_VIRTUALENVS_IN_PROJECT=true \
    POETRY_NO_INTERACTION=1 \
    PYSETUP_PATH="/opt/pysetup" \
    VENV_PATH="/opt/pysetup/.venv"

ENV PATH="$POETRY_HOME/bin:$VENV_PATH/bin:$PATH"

FROM python-base as builder-base
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y curl build-essential

RUN curl -sSL https://install.python-poetry.org | python3 -

WORKDIR $PYSETUP_PATH
COPY poetry.lock pyproject.toml ./

RUN poetry install --no-root

FROM python-base as production
ENV FASTAPI_ENV=production
COPY --from=builder-base $PYSETUP_PATH $PYSETUP_PATH
COPY . /app/
WORKDIR /app

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install --no-install-recommends  -y locales
RUN sed -i -e 's/# de_DE.UTF-8 UTF-8/de_DE.UTF-8 UTF-8/' /etc/locale.gen \
    && locale-gen

RUN cp /app/mksp_backend/config.example.py /app/mksp_backend/config.py

CMD ["uvicorn", "mksp_backend.main:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "80"]
```

Edit:

After some further troubleshooting, I figured out that downgrading FastAPI from `0.85.0` to `0.84.0` (and consequently also starlette from `0.20.4` to `0.19.1`) works around the issue. Looks like this was introduced in the most recent FastAPI version.

Also, dropping all http middlewares (`@app.middleware("http")`) works around the issue in `0.85.0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out FastAPI was on `0.84.0` on my local system and `0.85.0` within the Docker environment. This version change also changed one dependency, being starlette from `0.20.4` to `0.19.1`.

Starlette `0.20.4` contains the following change which seems to be causing the issue: https://github.com/encode/starlette/pull/1609/files

I'm using a custom http middleware as below to catch exceptions and ensure proper log formatting for our logging environment.

```
# Add middleware to catch all exceptions
@app.middleware("http")
async def exception_handler(request: Request, call_next):

    try:
        return await call_next(request)
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error("An unexpected error occured during request: {0}".format(str(e)))
        logger.info(
            "Traceback is: {0}".format(str(traceback.format_tb(e.__traceback__, 10)))
        )

        return JSONResponse(
            content={
                "message": "Custom Message"
            },
            status_code=500,
        )
```

With this middleware in place, it looks like the generator yielding the DB connection is not jumped back to in order to close the session. For some reason, the JSONResponse object being returned doesn't work anymore and the most recent version.

I do not understand the starlette flow and code enough to understand the root cause, but will report this issue in the issue tracker and try to remember updating here if the issue gets resolved.